# Calling js method onClick failed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, navigation, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have been trying to go from one page to another using native script but an error message keeps appearing when I click on the login button saying "calling js method failed, failed to load component form module: login

```
<template>
<Page>
<ActionBar title="form" />
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout id="registerform" class="registerform">
   <TextField v-model="email" input="email"></TextField>
    <TextField v-model="password" input="password"></TextField>
     <Button text="Login" @tap="onloginTap" />
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
</Page>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "registerform",
data() {
    return {
        email: "",
        password: ""
    };
},
methods:{
onloginTap: function(args) {
    const button = args.object;
    const page = button.page;
    page.frame.navigate("login");
}}
 };

</script>
```

Comment: The docs cover an example of how to navigate to a different component: https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/routing/manual-routing/

Your `onloginTap` method should use the `this.$navigateTo(SomePage)` method to navigate to a new page. Note that you will have to import the target page first: `import SomePage from './SomePage'`. I have started rewriting the docs to make this clearer, you can take a look at the early draft of the new page here: https://deploy-preview-331--nativescript-vue.netlify.com/en/docs/routing/navigation/

Comment: I have imported the target page but when I add the this.$navigateTo(nextPage) it's giving me the same error.

Comment: Could you share your code in a playground? Also see the playground from the draft document for the basic example: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=Gsxbge could help you identify the problem in your code!

Comment: Yes: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=nMr00V

Comment: In your playground, you have the `HelloWorld.vue` component - I don't see any import in that file. See fixed/commented playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=F3IgqM